# C++ How to fix an incompatible data type initialization?

Tags: c++

Hi I am trying to create a function to calculate distance between 2 places using the Haversine Formula.

I created a function for this and included `<cmath>` and defined `_USE_MATH_DEFINE`,

```
  Travel distanceTo(Travel travel){

    double a = 0, c = 0, dlat = 0, dlon = 0, lon2 = 0,lon1 = 0,lat2 = 0,lat1 = 0,distance = 0;
    double R = 637300;

    dlon = lon2 - lon1 * (M_PI/180);
    dlat = lat2 - lat1 * (M_PI/180);
    a = pow((sin(dlat / 2)), 2) + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * pow((sin(dlon / 2)), 2);
    c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a));
    distance =  R * c;

   return distance;

}
```

I am very new to c++ and possess fairly basic programming knowledge. I am trying to call this method in a **main.cpp** file. As such
`double distance = school.distanceTo(home)`. As expected I get an error warning me that double is not compatible with type Travel. I know I haven't referenced/used travel in the actual function, but I don't know how to properly implement it.

Any example with the correct way to do this is much appericiated.

The Travel object contains `(double lat, double long, string place, int time)`

Comment: Look at the function signature `Travel distanceTo(Travel travel)`.  Did you mean to have the first `Travel` there?

Comment: Presumably the type `Travel` is defined somewhere.   Include the header that defines it, and use `Travel` instead of `double`.

Comment: Tbh I am not quite sure, I was looking at examples and it seemed to be what they tend to do.

Comment: @LovesPie If you want to return a `double` from the function then that is what you need to put in for the return type in the function signature.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `travel` somewhere in your function?

Answer (score 1):

Just change return type of that function from Travel to double.

```
double distanceTo(Travel travel){
```

Comment: Omg was that it? Yeah it worked thanks.